# How to check if a key exists in Partial?

Tags: typescript

I have an object typed Partial. I want to check if a given key exists in the object. The below code doesn't work. Does anybody know how to? I'm using Typescript 4.6. Thanks in advance.

```
type Name = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'bird'

function(obj: Partial<Record<Name, number>>, name: Name) {
  // check a given name exists in obj
  if (name in obj) {
    const v = obj[name] // number or undefined
  }
  // Wait, how about dot notation? 
  if ('dog' in obj) {
    const v = obj.dog  // number or undefined
  }
  if (obj.dog !== undefined) {
    const v = obj.dog  // number or undefined
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't refine the type of your `obj` argument, even within each of those conditions it will still be `Partial<Record<Name, number>>`.

However, you can narrow the type of a variable that was assigned the value of that property in `obj`. For example:

```
type Name = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'bird'

function fn(obj: Partial<Record<Name, number>>, name: Name) {
  // check a given name exists in obj
  const v1 = obj[name];
  if (v1) {
    // v1: number
  }

  const v2 = obj.dog;
  if (v2) {
    // v2: number
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgW2gXigcgCYHsDmaoA+6AxnMPkWgEYCWAThmgFBMBmArgHbHA1adRWnABRYqAKwBcUAApw6vOABsAPACUIxLAxXwkAGiid2CKhDoA+C4c6II0vRACUUAN5MoUAPReoxABaaANZQcFA4NABuEAK2SFAQAB40AM7AKVA0AmLiHn78aVCRAIxQqDkA2nEQALoA3Hk0rFDCJS7unp4+RcXSxqbmeQC+LJ5anIWRAExlUDkAdNg4DZ5NLdPteV2+030mZnTDTENAA)

TypeScript doesn't do that level of type narrowing where it would apply to only a single property of an object. I believe the only time when checking an object's properties can narrow the type of object is when you're working with a [disciminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

This is why, for example, you can do things like this:

```
type MyType = {
  key: 'a',
  value: number,
} | {
  key: 'b',
  value: string;
};

function (arg: MyType) {
  if (arg.key === 'a') {
    // arg.value: number
  } else {
    // arg.value: string
  }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUoGsIgC4oByAQ2IBosoA3UgGwFcIiA7RgWwCMIAnKgL5QAPump5CJLpWp0mLKAGdgvAJasA5gG4MAnRgBmjVgGNgqgPasoAClK8NROIkgBKMdlUHb9jQDoJKGRgknJ3TGxsAHooqF8-OWY2Th5eaiEIekVoCMiYuIcEhiSlFXUNdN0MIA)

Comment: For more information about discriminated union: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions

Comment: Thanks @Watanabe.N, that's what I had meant to link to in my answer but it looks like I pasted the same TypeScript Playground link twice by mistake. I'll fix the link for discriminated unions in my answer.

Comment: Hahaha, Thanks! I thought that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

```
type Name = 'dog' | 'cat' | 'bird'

function test(obj: Partial<Record<Name, number>>, name: Name) {

  // First you assign the value to a const
  const v = obj[name];
  
  // then you test the value of that const
  if(v !== undefined){
    // do stuff with `v`, now type is inferred correctly
    console.log(v);
  }
}
```

Demo: https://tsplay.dev/N9EQqN